# Setting up a counter in Tex4HT Configuration to use in html

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex, document-configuration

I want to add a collapsible panel header to some text, to do this I need to define some IDs, I can't use `\thesubsubsection` because it comes with dots (2.0.1 for example). So I want to use a simple counter such as:

```
\newcounter{index}
\setcounter{index}{1}
\newcommand{\ppindex}{\arabic{index}\stepcounter{index}}
```

I want to use a similar behavior in my htlatex configfile so `\Index` expands to this counter:

```
\ConfigureEnv{lstlisting}{\HCode{\Hnewline
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion\Index">\Hnewline
  <div class="panel panel-default">\Hnewline
    <div class="panel-heading">\Hnewline
      <h4 class="panel-title">\Hnewline
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion\Index" href="#collapse\Index">\Hnewline
          Click to expand\Hnewline
        </a>\Hnewline
      </h4>\Hnewline
    </div>\Hnewline
    <div id="collapse\Index" class="panel-collapse collapse">\Hnewline
      <div class="panel-body">\Hnewline
                <pre class="prettyprint"><p>\Hnewline}}
{\HCode{</p></pre>\Hnewline
      </div>\Hnewline
    </div>\Hnewline
  </div>\Hnewline
</div>\Hnewline}}{}{}
```

I was thinking of using `\thesection`, or `\thesubsubsection` in my case but I get a wrong number in my generated html. Even after redefining it to \arabic{subsubsection} gives me zero for \thesubsubsection.

Thanks @michal.h21, I wanted to make my code snippets collapsable.

[image: Collapsed code]

And expand when you click it

[image: Expanded Code]

Thanks to you and the `\CurSecHaddr` macro, I was able to change my Objects `id`s to the following:

`id="accordionx1-80001"`, so now laTeX generates valid ids for each piece of `lstlisting` I add.

This is environment configuration for my `lstlisting`:

```
\ConfigureEnv{lstlisting}{\HCode{
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion\CurSecHaddr">\Hnewline
  <div class="panel panel-default">\Hnewline
    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="\#accordion\CurSecHaddr" href="\#collapse\CurSecHaddr">\Hnewline
     <div class="panel-heading">\Hnewline
      <h4 class="panel-title">\Hnewline
                    <FONT style="font-size:15px" COLOR="\#FE2E2E">View Code</FONT> <span class="pull-right clickable"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i></span>\Hnewline
                    </h4>\Hnewline
    </div>\Hnewline
        </a>\Hnewline
    <div id="collapse\CurSecHaddr" class="panel-collapse collapse">\Hnewline
      <div class="panel-body">\Hnewline
                <pre class="prettyprint"><p>\Hnewline}}
{\HCode{</p></pre>\Hnewline
      </div>\Hnewline
    </div>\Hnewline
  </div>\Hnewline
</div>\Hnewline}}{}{}
```

It stills need some work done, but I am thing of doing that with post compilation scripting since I need some generated parts erased.

Of course there is more than this code, you need to add some `JS` code just for the `glyphicon` to work.

The site is `http://claudiordgz.github.io/GoodrichTamassiaGoldwasser/` and the code is in `https://github.com/claudiordgz/GoodrichTamassiaGoldwasser/tree/gh-pages` in case anyone wants to see it. It is still in a very ugly alpha state but at least I can start pushing content like its hot.

Comment: Hi Claudio, could you please add complete example? I don't really understand what you are trying to do. If you want to get id of current sectioning command, try `\CurSecHaddr`

Comment: @michal.h21 Really sorry for not answering before, I was out of town, please see edit.

Comment: @michal.h21 Btw your suggestion works wonders, please put it as an answer.

Comment: it's OK, I provided little bit different solution, but it still needs some clean up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id` of current sectioning command is stored in `\CurSecHaddr` macro, it may look in a following way:

```
x1-130006.7
```

this looks cryptic, but in fact `x` is just prefix, `1` is number of current file (because multiple files may be produced in `tex4ht` run), `13000` means that this is 13th sectioning command and `6.7` is subsection number.

I don't think you should use current section id to construct a new one, custom counter updated every `listings` usage would be better, I think:

```
\newcount\ppindex
\def\theppindex{\the\ppindex}
\def\steppindex{\global\advance\ppindex by 1\relax}
```

For stuff dealing with linking and id's it is better to use `\Link` command instead of direct use of `<a>` elements. In your case it doesn't matter, because you are linking to the parent element, but I will show it anyway.

This command is to be used in this way:

```
\Link[baseurl attributes]{target id}{current id}link text\EndLink
```

baseurl is useful only for linking to external pages, it is created automatically for pages from the same document.

it is possible to create new command which will use cross referencing mechanism but which will produce different element than `<a>`:

```
\LinkCommand\Accordion{div,href,id}
```

now we can use

```
\Accordion[ class="panel-group"]{}{accordion\theppindex}...\EndAccordion
```

and

```
 <div 
  id="accordion1" class="panel-group"  >...</div>
```

is produced. Similarly, for the second link, use:

```
\Link[ class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="\#accordion\theppindex"]{collapse\theppindex}{}
```

and

```
<a 
href="#collapse1" class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" >
```

is produced.

Full example:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,info}
\newcount\ppindex
\LinkCommand\Accordion{div,href,id}
\def\theppindex{\the\ppindex}
\def\steppindex{\global\advance\ppindex by 1\relax}
\ConfigureEnv{lstlisting}{%
\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP%
\steppindex%
%<div class="panel-group" id="accordion\CurSecHaddr">\Hnewline
\Accordion[ class="panel-group"]{}{accordion\theppindex}%
\HCode{%
  <div class="panel panel-default">\Hnewline}
    %<a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="\#accordion\the\ppindex" href="\#collapse\CurSecHaddr">\Hnewline}
    \Link[ class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="\#accordion\theppindex"]{collapse\theppindex}{}\HCode{\Hnewline
     <div class="panel-heading">\Hnewline
      <h4 class="panel-title">\Hnewline%
    <FONT style="font-size:15px" COLOR="\#FE2E2E">View Code</FONT> <span class="pull-right clickable"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i></span>%                    
    </h4>\Hnewline%
    </div>\Hnewline}%
    \EndLink\HCode{\Hnewline%
    <div id="collapse\CurSecHaddr" class="panel-collapse collapse">\Hnewline
      <div class="panel-body">%
  %<pre class="prettyprint"><p>}}%
  }}
{\IgnorePar\HCode{%
      </div>\Hnewline
    </div>\Hnewline
  </div>\Hnewline}
\EndAccordion%
%</div>
}{}{}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

note that linking commands must be used outside of `\HCode`. I also played little bit with paragraphs and removed redundant `<pre>` element and some `\Hnewline`s, in order to reduce empty vertical space.

Comment: This is amazing, I'm sorry for my slopy and ugly config. Information regarding Tex4HT is well buried. I need to read some more to do cleaner configurations. Thank you Michal.

Comment: Could you tell me where to get more information on LinkCommand and JSLink?

Comment: sure, basic info is in http://www.tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn11.html#QQ1-11-54 (you can click to numbers at line beginning to see some examples)

Comment: also see html version of `tex4ht` sources: http://michal-h21.github.io/src4ht/, especially http://michal-h21.github.io/src4ht/tex4ht-infose1.html#x6-30002.1